# num.charAt does not work

Tags: javascript

When I run this code, console returns "Type Error: num.charAt is not a function". Why does this happen and how can I fix it.

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  var total = "";

  if (num >= 1000){
    total += "M";
  }
  if (num.charAt(1) >= 5){
    total += "D"; 
  }
  return total;
}

convertToRoman(1500);
```

Comment: `charAt` is available only on `string`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp

Comment: what should num.charAt(1) >= 5 do?

Answer (score 1):

`#String.charAt` doesn't work on numbers. If you wish it to work properly, transform your `num` variable into a string, e.g.:

- `('' + num).charAt(1)`
- `num.toString().charAt(1)`
- `String(num).charAt(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The charAt() method returns the specified character from a string. Since your input is of type number it fails.

Comment: Either `num >= 1000` or `num.charAt(1) >= 5`. You cannot have both work…

Answer (score 0):

```
("" + num).charAt(1)
```

Try to convert `num` to String.